# Using Selectors in a View Controller with objc exposed functions located in the Parent View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, selector

I am creating a Page View Controller where I would like to create two objc exposed functions that exist in the PageViewController:

```
@objc func nextPage() {
  // navigates to next view controller
}

@objec func previousPage() {
  // navigates to previous view controller
}
```

From one of the view controller's the PageViewController displays, PageOneViewController, I would like to use this function with a selector on an action:

```
var pageViewController: PageViewController? {
    guard let parent = self.parent as? PageViewController else {
        return nil
    }
    return parent
}

button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.pageViewController?.nextPage), for: .touchUpInside)
```

However, when I do this, I get the error: `'-[MyProject.PageOneViewController nextPage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x....`

Do selectors only work within the same class? Can you not use selector functions this way? I mainly didn't want to have to write a `nextPage` function in all of my view controllers that the PageViewController displays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `target` you specify in `addTarget` is the class that must contain the `action` that will be called.

Change:

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.pageViewController?.nextPage), for: .touchUpInside)
```

to:

```
button.addTarget(self.pageViewController, action: #selector(PageViewController.nextPage), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Note that now the target is `self.pageViewController` and the action is the `nextPage` method of the `PageViewController` class.